# Cálculo de duração com intervalo

Tags: php, input, data

Bom dia, gostaria de saber que alguém me consegue ajudar a criar uma interface em conjunto com o cálculo, em PHP, entre horas de trabalho com minutos de pausa.
Ou seja, teríamos uma hora de entrada inserida pelo utilizador e uma hora de saída. Num input à parte um input de horas/minutos de pausa.

Tenho tentado seriamente fazer os cálculos necessários para dar correctamente, porém as horas e minutos menos o intervalo, têm dado mal.

Deixo aqui um pouco do código que tenho feito.

```
<input type="text" name="horai" id="horai" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; padding: 6px;" required/> 
<input type="text" name="horaf" id="horaf" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; padding: 6px;" required/>
```

```
<?php

if($_POST['horai'] > $_POST['horaf']){
    $total = (24 - $_POST['horai'] + $_POST['horaf']);
}else{
    $total = $_POST['horaf'] - $_POST['horai'];
}

$iTime= strtotime($_POST['horai']);
$fTime= strtotime($_POST['horaf']);

if($fTime> $iTime){
    $diferenca = $fTime- $iTime; 
    $semintervalo = date('H:i', $diferenca); 
} else {
    $diferenca = (24 - $iTime) + $fTime;
    $semintervalo = date('H:i', $diferenca);
}

$tempodepausa= strtotime($_POST['pausa']);
$tempodepausaaux= $diferenca- $semintervalo;
$comintervalo = date('H:i', $tempodepausaaux);

echo 'Diferença entre Horas (s): '.$diferenca.'<br/>';
echo 'Diferença entre Horas (H:m): '.$semintervalo.'<br/>';
echo 'Tempo útil (H:m): '.$comintervalo.'<br/>';
echo 'Tempo útil (s): '.$tempodepausaaux;

?>
```

Comment: E como devem ser aa entradaa nesses inputs? posso digitar 08:00 para inicial e 15:00 para final? ou 16 abril 23:00 e 17 de abril 2:00 que o código vai funcionar corretamente?

Comment: 10:00 - 15:00 do próprio dia funciona. Para dias diferentes não testei porque separei o código.

Comment: No meu código no PC funciona perfeitamente. Não percebo como te dá aqueles valores. Vê se o type="date" ou "datetime"

Comment: Pois é, tem que digitar corretamente  no formato `ano-mes-dia hh:mm:ss` para funcionar corretamente. Trabalheira ao digitar!!!

Comment: No seu pc para inicial `2018-04-16 8:00:00` para final `2018-04-17 8:00:00` (24 horas)  e intervalo de 1 hora quanto retorna?

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo o problema não está no código em si. O problema está na no time_zone. Vou editar a resposta.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho, não estou questionando sobre o código, estou questionando sobre a entrada de dados nos inputs que são tipo text. Dessa forma o usuário terá que ser adivinho ou ficar tentando, tentando ....

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo sim.. eu entendi. Mas faça o teste agora. Não irá alterar o valor. O problema era justamente isso. De qualquer forma, obrigado. Como eu não tinha testado em outro servidor, isso traria problemas.

Comment: @AndreiCoelho, blz, o meu proposito era ajudar o AP a validar os inputs com as entradas corretamente para que o código funcione. Veja que qualquer tipo de entrada é aceita. Mas enfim .... deixa pra lá .... faltou interesse da parte dele

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo sim! Isso sim! É importante ele fazer validações ANTES de iniciar esse processo.

Comment: Uso um data picker pelo meio e valida-me automaticamente. Isto tudo foi só para conseguir saber que cálculos estavam errados. O Andrei ajudou e muito.

Comment: @White tranquilo amigo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu fiz da seguinte forma:

```
// cada servidor tem timezone diferente
// para corrigir isso, basta adicionar a linha abaixo que ficará padrão
// explicarei melhor no edit 

date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 

$iTime= strtotime($_POST['horai']);
$fTime= strtotime($_POST['horaf']);

$tempopausaINI = strtotime("00:00:00");
$tempodepausa = strtotime($_POST['pausa']);
$tempoPausaTotal = abs($tempopausaINI - $tempodepausa);

// esse if apenas assegura que os valores formam convertidos
if ($tempodepausa !== false && $iTime !== false && $fTime !== false) {
    if($fTime > $iTime){
        $diferenca = ($fTime - $iTime); 
    } else {
        $diferenca = abs($iTime - $fTime); // o abs coloca o valor para positivo
    }
    $semintervalo = date('H:i:s', $diferenca);
    $tempodepausaaux = $diferenca - $tempoPausaTotal;
    $comintervalo = date('H:i:s', $tempodepausaaux);

    echo 'Diferença entre Horas (s): '.strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$semintervalo .'UTC').'<br/>';
    echo 'Diferença entre Horas (H:m): '.$semintervalo.'<br/>';
    echo 'Tempo útil (H:m): '.$comintervalo.'<br/>';
    echo 'Tempo útil (s): '.strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$comintervalo .'UTC');
}
```

**Os problemas eu identifiquei:**

1) Nesta linha abaixo, você tenta subtrair um timestamp de uma date. Não vai funcionar:

```
$tempodepausaaux= $diferenca- $semintervalo;
```

2) Cada hora no timestamp tem um valor de 3600 inteiro. Na linha abaixo você subtrai o número 24 do tempo inicial, que vai apenas torna-lo negativo com uma diferença de valor errada.

```
$diferenca = (24 - $iTime) + $fTime;
```

3) Esta condição não serve para nada, talvez você tenha usado para testes:

```
if($_POST['horai'] > $_POST['horaf']){
    $total = (24 - $_POST['horai'] + $_POST['horaf']);
}else{
    $total = $_POST['horaf'] - $_POST['horai'];
}
```

4) Um outro problema é o tempo de pausa. Quando você transforma o tempo de hora/minuto em timestamp sem colocar um valor inicial para fazer comparação. Essa comparação se faz na data inicial de "1970-01-01". Por isso alterei o valor de:

```
$tempodepausa= strtotime($_POST['pausa']);
```

Para:

```
$tempopausaINI = strtotime("00:00:00");
$tempodepausa = strtotime($_POST['pausa']);
$tempoPausaTotal = abs($tempopausaINI - $tempodepausa);
```

Assim, você terá o valor correto em timestamp da pausa.

Enfim, sua lógica estava correta, apenas alguns detalhes estavam errados.

**EDIT**

O [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) por padrão ele retorna em segundos a data inicio ***January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT*** até a data estipulada. Porém cada servidor pode ser configurado com um fuso horário diferente. Se você converter um esse valor em `timestamp` para o date() sem alterar o fuso, a data / hora podem ser alterados. Pois se no timestamp a data inicial é em 1 de Janeiro as 00 horas `GMT`, para outros servidor esse inicio pode começar mais tarde alterando o valor esperado.

Tem uma alteração neste `if` também:

```
if($fTime > $iTime){
    $diferenca = ($fTime - $iTime); 
} else {
    $diferenca = abs($iTime - $fTime); // o abs coloca o valor para positivo
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Andrei. O 3) era no caso de passar por exemplo de 16 abril 23:00 para 17 de abril 2:00 da manhã. O 2) não sei como não dei conta, devo ter me confundido imenso. De resto compreendi perfeitamente.

Comment: @White tranquilo, se a resposta estiver correta, não esqueça de coloca-la como certa. Abraço!

Comment: Está perfeita! Já ficou como correcta? Finalmente, dá certo. Obrigado Andrei, se for preciso recomendar-te ainda mais é só dizer.

Comment: @White está ótimo amigo! Obrigado! Abraço!